# Join two files based on shared key

Tags: linux, text-processing, join

I have two files I would like to join based on the bakery store number.

**[File 1] bakedGoods.txt**

```
1:Chocolate Cookies:111
2:Banana Muffins:222
3:Apple Pie:333
4:Strawberry Cheesecake:444
5:Pineapple Turnover:555
```

*Where column 1 is the number of the item, column 2 is the item name, and column 3 is the store number.*

**[File 2] bakeryStores.txt**

```
111:Cookies Cookies Cookies
222:Bellas Desserts Co.
333:Apples N' Sweets
444:Cheesecake Emporium
777:Estrellas Bakery
888:Suzy's Baked Goods
```

*Where column 1 is the bakery store number and column 2 is the name of the bakery.*

**My goal is to join the information that has the same bakery store number** by using the *join* command (I assume that is the best way). This means column 3 for file 1 and column 1 for file 2. **As well as** display a message "Not in store" for the empty fields that are not pair-able. (Which I assume using the option -e"Not in store" is the best way to go. The below is what I am trying to achieve.

```
111:Chocolate Cookies:Cookies Cookies Cookies
222:Banana Muffins:Bellas Desserts Co.
333:Apple Pie:Apples N' Sweets
444:Strawberry Cheesecake:Cheesecake Emporium
Not in store
Not in store
```

I try to join the two files by store number, I am also using the -e option (for the message), but nothing changes. I see no output either.

I tried `join -1 3 -2 1 -e "Not in store" bakedGoods.txt bakeryStores.txt` I understand what I want to do and how to do it, just not sure why it is not displaying anything. Usually, when I join or combine files, without appending, I can see the result right away. I appended but the two files remain the same.

Comment: What part have you made of **your** homework so far and where exactly you need some clarification?

Comment: Not homework, just for practice.. I guess it's my fault for using an example involving bakeries.. Anyways! I understand how joining works, but not sure what I am missing. Specifically, I type join -1 3 -2 1 -e "Not in store" bakedGoods.txt bakeryStores.txt
-1 3 indicating the common field in file 1 (column 3)
-2 1 inciditing the common field in file 2 (column 1)

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Without this, it is impossible to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thank you for the edits. I apologize for ambiguity and will be more conscious about detail next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer these two questions, and you will solve your problem.

What is the default field delimiter (for `join`)? How do you change it?

Comment: Is each file sorted on the join field? https://linux.die.net/man/1/join

Comment: They previously were not sorted when I first created the text files but I did after (before posting on stack exchange) however, after tinkering around, I believe I achieved what I wanted to do. :) I feel like there is a better way though.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I was missing exactly that.. the delimeter! To the previous code I mentioned above, I needed a -t':' !